# Comparing two date fields in MDX

Tags: mdx, date-comparison

I have sql query like:

```
Select Count(*) 
from   [Response] 
where  ResponseEndDate < ValidDate
```

How do I write this in `MDX`?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].cnt
AS 
([Employee].[Department Name].MEMBERS
,[Employee].[Start Date].&[2002-02-05T00:00:00]
:
 [Employee].[Start Date].&[2003-02-05T00:00:00]).COUNT

SELECT
  [Measures].cnt ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a little bit of explanation.

Comment: this is not really helping to illustrate date comparison in `mdx`